# Moving on with points using check boxes and if statement

Tags: c#

I'm creating a C# quiz using windows forms on visual studio. 
The question is "What is the average beats per minute for a healthy male and female teenage student?"
Then the possible answers are four check boxes the user must select two answers.
There is a button the user hits when they have selected their answers and it moves them onto the next form.
How do I use an IF statement to validate that the user has selected ANY two answers(Not necessarily the correct one) before moving on. 
The user must have selected two answers before they can move on or a message box will show ensuring that they know to pick two. I am struggling as to what to fill into the brackets after the word IF. Many thanks!

```
private void btnNextQuestion_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       if ()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please select two answers.");
        }
        else
        {
            this.Hide();
            frmQuestionFour frm = new frmQuestionFour();
            frm.Show();
```

Comment: How about: `int count = (int)chk1.Checked + (int)chk2.Checked + (int)chk3.Checked + (int)chk4.Checked; if (count == 2) { ...} else { ... }` ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to do something like this:

```
int count = 0;
if (chk1.Checked) count++;
if (chk2.Checked) count++;
if (chk3.Checked) count++;
if (chk4.Checked) count++;
if (count == 2)
```

If you have placed the checkbox references into a collection you can also use Linq to do this:

```
if (checkboxes.Where(chk => chk.Checked).Count() == 2)
```

And if the four checkboxes are the **only** checkboxes on the screen you could try this:

```
if (Controls.OfType<CheckBox>().Where(chk => chk.Checked).Count() == 2)
```

Comment: Last time I checked you cannot cast `bool` to `int` in C#.

Comment: Where the he... did I get that from? I must check some old code but in the meantime I've edited out that part since you're right. I think perhaps I'm thinking of the Convert class since I have database code that reads `bit` values from SQL Server and puts the result into Int32 values as 0 or 1, but now I'm not so sure.

Comment: OK, so `Convert.ChangeType` does it, must be why I thought that was possible, but you're right, `(int)bool` does not work.

Comment: You can do `Convert.ToInt32(chk1.Checked)`

Comment: Yeah, but then I'd rather (personally) write the code as it stands in my answer. This was all quite embarrassing to be honest. In my defence I tend to write framework classes that deal with conversion of data on the reflection level, like ORM-type things, but still, quite embarrassing :)